# Java solution to transform the data in parent,Child,Grand Child tree format as mentioned below

Tags: java

At present I am pulling my folder structure data as mentioned below.

```
{
{
"parent": "TestParent1"
"Child" : "TestSub1"
"GrnadChild":"TestGrandChild1"
}, 
{
  "parent": "TestParent1"
  "Child" : "TestSub1"
  "GrnadChild":"TestGrandChild2"
},
{
  "parent": "TestParent1"
  "Child" : "TestSub2"
  "GrnadChild":"TestGrandChild3"
  },
{
 "parent": "TestParent1"
 "Child" : "TestSub2"
 "GrnadChild":"TestGrandChild4"
}
}
```

I have a parent folder that consists 2 sub folder and each sub folder consists 2 grand folders.
I need the data to be framed in below json format.

```
 {
  "parent": "TestParent1",
  {
   "Child" : "TestSub1"
     {
      "GrnadChild" :
       {
        "TestGrandChild1",
        "TestGrandChild2"
       }
     },
   "Child" : "TestSub2"
     {
      "GrnadChild" :
      {
        "TestGrandChild3",
        "TestGrandChild4"
      }
    }
 },
"parent": "TestParent2",
 {
  "Child" : "TestSub3"
   {
    "GrnadChild" :
     {
       "TestGrandChild5",                                                              
       "TestGrandChild6"
     }
   },
   "Child" : "TestSub4"
   {
    "GrnadChild" :
    {
     "TestGrandChild7",                                                              
     "TestGrandChild8"
    }
   }
  }
  }
```

Kindly assist me to wirte the java logic and Appreciate your help.

Comment: Duplicate:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java ...maybe others

Comment: There are many Java libraries for parsing JSON: Jackson, GSON, org.json.  Pick one, read a tutorial, and come back if you have more questions.

Comment: Hi gagarwa,It seems the url you provided is different than what i am asking for. i need to display the data in tree format. Thank you for the reply anyhow.

Comment: You want to reformat the input...the libraries used are the same.  If you are ok serializing the data into a data model, you can use Jackson.  Then you can convert to your desired model, and output using Jackson.  To modify, use Jackson Annotations.  I will add this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Serialize JSON to Object

   ```
   String json;
   FolderStruc original = new ObjectMapper()
      .readerFor(FolderStruc.class)
      .readValue(json);
   ```
2. Convert to Desired Object Model

   ```
   DesiredStruc desired = new DesiredStruc(original);
   ```
3. De-serialize Object to JSON

   ```
   String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(desired);
   ```

If you are having any issues with correctly mapping your model to the desired output, try these annotations:

https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code for implementation. You have to add **json-simple jar** to your library

```
    JSONArray grandchild = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray child = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray parent = new JSONArray();
    
    grandchild.add("GC1");
    grandchild.add("GC1");
    
    child.add("C1");
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("GC", grandchild);
    child.add(obj);
    
    parent.add("P");
    obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("C", child);
    parent.add(obj);
    

    System.out.println(parent);
```

Output generated will look like :

```
["P",{"C":["C1",{"GC":["GC1","GC1"]}]}]
```

Comment: Hi Bhuvan, Thank you. But i need a logic to add parent and sub folders and grand folders based on the conditions. The data i given is just sample which is coming from DB.